# Error importing Zookeeper libzookeeper_mt.so.2 in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, apache-zookeeper

I am having issues trying to import this .so file in Python...I added this to my `/etc/bashrc` and `source`'d it to make it reload...no luck so far...

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib`

The file DOES exist at `/usr/local/lib/lobzookeeper_mt.so.2`

```
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/zookeeper.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/zookeeper.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libzookeeper_mt.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea what to do at this point, anyone have an idea on what I am doing wrong?  I am using Centos 6 64 bit too btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attempting to load a library will, confusingly, fail with "no such file or directory" if a dependency of the library you're trying to load cannot be found. Run `ldd`:

```
ldd /path/to/your/library.so
```

and look for the words "not found" to check if this is the case.

Comment: Well i solved it..i forgot the keyword "export" in my bashrc in front  of the line posted above.  Thanks for showing that it was installed properly though.

Comment: Hah, that'd do it too. I'll leave this answer up in case it helps anyone else, though.

Answer (score 2):

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

1. temporary way：export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
2. permanent way：edit /root/.bashrc, add following lines:

   - export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib