# libzookeeper_mt.so.2 and libmosquitto.so.1 not found

Tags: apache-kafka, adapter, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

So here is the problem: I installed zookeeper(prereq) for kafka using apt-get. Also, unzipped a tar file onto my image.

When i am running the kafka adapter to connect kafka producer to my ESP(SAS Event stream processing) I am getting an error for following two files not found or shared:

```
 libzookeeper_mt.so.2
 libmosquitto.so.1
```

I did look around for a quite few questions on SO, but didnt find any alternative than someone saying that these files are located in

```
/usr/local/lib directory
```

Unfortunately my directory contains only the following files:

```
vagrant@packer-virtualbox-iso-1421293493:/usr/local/lib$ ls
librdkafka.a  librdkafka++.a  librdkafka.so  librdkafka++.so  
librdkafka.so.1  librdkafka++.so.1  pkgconfig  python2.7  python3.4  site_ruby
```

Can anyone tell me where can i locate these 2 files so that i can share them to run my kafka adapters? FYI, following is the link to the documentation of kafka adapters in case anyone wants to know more:
http://go.documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=espca&docsetVersion=4.2&docsetTarget=p0sbfix2ql9xpln1l1x4t9017aql.htm&locale=en

@alvits suggested that the libs are not installed, so i will be trying a separate installation again. Still any help during this will be appreciated!

Comment: `dpkg -L zookeeper | grep -E 'libzookeeper|libmosquito'` will filter the list of files of the `zookeeper` package. You will find the location of the library in there.

Comment: This listed everything except for the *.so files which i need.. :(. I did try to locate them physically but without success. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536171/error-importing-zookeeper-libzookeeper-mt-so-2-in-python

This question mentions the files might reside by default in /usr/local/lib/libzookeeper_mt.so.2, but /usr/local/lib doesnt have thse files. Can you help me figure out if this is an installation issue or something to do with vagrant?

Comment: That means the library isn't installed or the library is in a separate package. Try `dpkg -L zookeeper-libs`.

Comment: looks like the lib isnt installed. I am getting the following issue:

    dpkg-query: package 'zookeeper-libs' is not installed
    Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
    and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.

@alvits thanks a lot. Will keep posted

Comment: You need _Zookeeper C client libraries_. What you installed is probably the _Zookeeper java client_, or perhaps the _Zookeeper C server binaries_

Comment: Would love to see a system independant answer which would enumerate the package name rpm, dpkg, brew, etc....